# MATE: how to increase window resizing area

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, desktop-customization, mate

I use MATE on CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 15.04 and with both I have trouble resizing windows. It seems like I have to click on a 1px size line to change and that's a bit difficult with touchpad sometimes.

Is there any way that I can increase this area without graphically changing the thickness of the borders? If not, how can I change the thickness of the window borders?

Would be nice to know for both CentOS and Ubuntu but if I know one I'll be able to figure out the other one :)

Thanks in advance

I know I can change sensitivity for my touchpad but I prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 14):

Answer taken from [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8498/how-can-i-make-the-draggable-window-border-thicker-without-changing-the-appeara):

1. This is a really [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/metacity/+bug/160311), still not fixed for metacity.
2. One workaround is to use great combo Alt + "Hold Right Mouse Button" and resize window according to nearest border
3. Another is to manually change theme border size. Default theme configuration file path: `/usr/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`.

   Following parameters change borders width:
     `<distance name="left_width" value="1"/>`
     `<distance name="right_width" value="1"/>`
     `<distance name="bottom_height" value="1"/>`

Comment: [Alt+RMB doesn't work on touchpads](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/resizing-borders-too-thin/17238/55), and if you scroll up in that thread, you'll what an amazing example of open source UI neglect this annoyance is.

Answer (score 2):

What's New in Mate 1.24 (https://mate-desktop.org/blog/) mentions:

> Finally added invisible resize borders. No more struggling to find a
> border to grab with your mouse!

Unfortunately I can find no documentation about how you use this new feature. It's not in mate-tweak-ui as far as I can see.

Comment: Haha! Only 4.5 years later they fix the issue? Thanks for the update but in the meanwhile I'm not longer using MATE and I'm probably not the only one ;)

Answer (score 1):

The experience of struggling to grab window edges is a Linux desktop classic. I have tried the above 'hack', altering the distance entries in the theme, without success.

I did, however, find it was a problem only with certain themes. For example, TraditionalGreen, included among basic default themes in many MATE implementations, has no trouble. The Windows-Server-2019-1.0 theme on gnome-look is also find, as are the Simply-Circles themes.

Comment: To say this issue is a Linux desktop classic and referring to anything Windows is a bit naughty. I have been working with Gnome, KDE and Unity for over 2 decades and it's really no problem in most common desktop environments for Linux/GNU.